# Unrecognized Selector sent to Instance in UI Textfield even after checking IB Outlets

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet, unrecognized-selector

So I'm creating a social media app in Xcode and am trying to create the signup button page. However, I noticed every time I tap on the username, password or any of the other textfields, instead of the ios keyboard popping up I get this error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

I've looked up how to solve the problem and it says to check your outlets. However, I've checked my outlets a million times and know they are correct. I've even broken and reconnected all of them just to be sure. I know the error pops up when I add the

`showKeyboard` and `hideKeyboard` functions. I don't know what to do to figure this out. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class sign_upVC: UIViewController {
    
    
    // Profile image
    @IBOutlet weak var AvaImg: UIImageView!
    
    
    // Text fields
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullnameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bioTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var webTxt: UITextField!
    
    
    // buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIButton!
    
    // scrollView
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    // reset default size
    var scrollViewHeight : CGFloat = 0
    
    
    // keyboard frame size
    var keyBoard = CGRect()
    
    
    // default func
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    
        
        // ScrollView frame sizes
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.view.frame.width,height: self.view.frame.height)
        scrollView.contentSize.height = self.view.frame.height
        scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
        
        // Check notification if keyboard is shown or not
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("showKeyboard:")), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("hideKeyboard:")), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        
        // declare keyboard if tapped
        let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("hideKeyboardTap:")))
        hideTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(hideTap)
    }
    
    // hide keyboard if tapped
    func hideKeyboardTap(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        
    }
    
    // show keyboard
    func showKeyboard(notification:NSNotification){

        // Define keyboard size
        keyBoard = ((notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue)!
        
        // move up UI
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.scrollView.frame.size.height = self.scrollViewHeight - self.keyBoard.height
        })
    
    }
    
    // hide keyboard
    func hideKeyboard(notification:NSNotification){
        
        // move down UI
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.scrollView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height
        })
    }
    
    // Tapped sign up
    @IBAction func signUpBtn_Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Sign up tapped")
    }
    
    
    // Tapped cancel
    @IBAction func cancelBtn_Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Cancel tapped")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: I m not sure about exact issue but one issue I see in your code is you have tap gesture added on self.view. So when you tap anywhere either button or textfield that gesture will invoked and "hideKeyboardTap" will be called.  Also instead of using selector with name "Selector(("showKeyboard:")" better to use #Selector

Comment: `let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboardTap(recognizer:)))` This will solve the crash issue

Answer (score 2):

Never say stuff like

```
Selector(("showKeyboard:"))
```

You don't know how to write the Objective C selector for these methods. Use Swift to help you! Write

```
#selector(showKeyboard)
```

And

```
@objc func showKeyboard(...
```

And so on.

Comment: I do that but then it gives me another error: `Type 'sign_upVC' has no member 'showKeyboard'`. What should I do now?